how to merge two System.Windows.Controls.Image objects?
I have seen a lot of examples merging two System.Drawing.Image/Bitmap objects to create a single image, but I'm trying to do it with System.Windows.Controls.Image objects.
For example, if I have the following objects:
System.Windows.Controls.Image image1;
System.Windows.Controls.Image image2;

How do I either merge both images into an existing image object? E.g.:
image1.Merge(image2, new Rect(0, 0, 15, 15);

The goal being to have a single image with the image contents of both images.
I've tried converting them to System.Drawing.Image objects, but other parts of my program require that they be System.Windows.Controls.Image objects.

do you want to merge them over each other? Side by side? Above each other? I'm not sure I understand what is meant with 'merge'.

You put the two images side by side in a Window (or form or user control); then take a "visual" (or screen capture) of the "client area" (or visual tree), and save that. You could overlap them if need be.

@Mayfair, merge one over the other. Example, one image shows the ocean, another image shows a boat. Merging would show the boat on the ocean.

@GerrySchmitz, I will look into that. Currently at work so won't have time for several hours. Is this a good example of what you're talking about?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124825/generating-a-screenshot-of-a-wpf-window

No; it's even simpler based on your previous comment: you have an image of a boat with a transparent background, and simply z-order it over the image of the ocean. I create "battle scenes" by just overlaying images with transparent backgrounds over maps; and move them around. You could sail your boat from one side to the other using a timer to move the image.

@GerrySchmitz, The image is going into a WPF Datagrid. Specifically, the Datagrid contains a list of entities. The first column is the name of the entity, and the second column shows the image representing that entity. For entities composed of only a single Image, it's easy to just display that Image in the Datagrid column. But some entities are composed of multiple Images. I'm trying to figure out how to merge all of those Images into a single Image. Not sure if that makes sense. So the images aren't really free floating around on the form/panel. They are being rendered in a Datagrid column.

You're assuming the data grid is a proper vehicle for this application. I disagree. You're saying what you want; I'm not at all clear on what you need.

How can you disagree on the proper vehicle for the application when by your own admission you do not know what I need? No further action is needed on your part, thank you.

You could use DrawingVisual and RenderTargetBitmap to create the overlapping image, then just change the Image.Source property. Here is an example:
public static class ImageExtensions
{
    public static void Merge(this Image image1, Image image2, Rect r)
    {
        // Get sources from each image
        BitmapImage source1 = (BitmapImage)image1.Source;
        BitmapImage source2 = (BitmapImage)image2.Source;

        // Overlap images and save to image 1
        image1.Source = OverlapImages(source1, source2, r);
    }

    private static BitmapSource OverlapImages(BitmapImage image1, BitmapImage image2, Rect r)
    {
        // Create a DrawingVisual to combine the images
        DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();
        using (DrawingContext ctx = visual.RenderOpen())
        {
            // Draw the first image
            ctx.DrawImage(image1, new Rect(0, 0, image1.Width, image1.Height));

            // Draw the second image on top
            ctx.DrawImage(image2, r);
        }

        // Render the visual into a RenderTargetBitmap
        RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
            (int)Math.Max(image1.PixelWidth, image2.PixelWidth),
            (int)Math.Max(image1.PixelHeight, image2.PixelHeight),
            96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

        renderBitmap.Render(visual);

        return renderBitmap;
    }
}

You can then use the extension in your code. Example:
 // Load data into image 1
 BitmapImage bmp1 = new BitmapImage();
 bmp1.BeginInit();
 bmp1.UriSource = new Uri("your path goes here");
 bmp1.EndInit();
 image1.Source = bmp1;

 // Load data into image 2
 BitmapImage bmp2 = new BitmapImage();
 bmp2.BeginInit();
 bmp2.UriSource = new Uri("your path goes here");
 bmp2.EndInit();
 image2.Source = bmp2;

 // Merge image 2 into image 1
 image1.Merge(image2, new Rect(15, 15, 100, 100));

The image1 will now display both the image1 and image2.
